# SQL: how to get last items?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a log for documents that go through my application. The log looks like this:

```
TABLE: log
==================================================
| log_id | document_id | status_code | timestamp |
==================================================
| 1      | 10          | 100         | 12345     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 10          | 200         | 23456     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I need a list of `document_id` that have been "stuck" in a certain `status_code` for a given duration (say 10 minutes; `timestamp` is Unix timestamp, btw). If a particular `document_id` is "stuck" in a certain `status_code`, that `status_code` will be the last `status_code` for that `document_id`.

How do I query this? The 2 things I'm not sure of:

1. How do I check if the document has been in a certain status for a certain period of time? I'm guessing I can use some sort of function/formula in my SQL (e.g. `now` - 10 minutes), but I don't know how to do that.
2. How do I check the duration of only the last status code?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? (Though I'm guessing `MySQL` is quite likely from your previous questions)

Comment: log_id for table log is the same for two different rows -- really??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT log.document_id
     , (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - log.timestamp) / 60
       AS MinutesSinceLastChange 
FROM log
  JOIN
    ( SELECT document_id
           , MAX(timestamp) AS last_change
      FROM log
      GROUP BY document_id
      HAVING (last_change < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60 * 10))  <-- that is 10 minutes
    ) AS grp
    ON  grp.document_id = log.document_id
    AND grp.last_change = log.timestamp
WHERE log.status_code = "200"             <-- code you want to check
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Column 'document_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie. Change the first select to `SELECT log.document_id`.

Answer (score 0):

For Your no. one and no. two question, this is my proposition for (I guess You are using MySQL):

```
SELECT 
    `document_id`, 
    SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(RPAD(`status_code`,5) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC), 1, 5) AS `last_status`,
    SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(RPAD(`status_code`,5) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC), 7, 5) AS `prev_status`,

    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC), 1, 19)) AS `last_timestamp`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC), 21, 19)) AS `prev_timestamp`
FROM `log`
GROUP BY `document_id`
HAVING `last_timestamp` - `prev_timestamp` > 60*10 AND `last_status` IN (100,200);
```

All right, what is happing there. We're grouping rows by document_id, and ordering status codes and timestamps inside GROUP_CONCAT to get the last and pre-last entry.

If Your status code can have more than 5 digits, then replace it RPAD(`status_code`,X), where X is maximal number of status_code length

60*10 - is 10 minutes

`last_status` IN (100,200) - status codes You want to get only.

Comment: The OP writes: "*If a particular document_id is "stuck" in a certain status_code, that status_code will be the last status_code for that document_id*". You don't have to check pre-last entry, only the last one.

Comment: though my status code is indeed integers, I don't think the solution needs to assume that. I think it just needs to find the last status code of that document.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT log.document_id, log.status_code, max(log.timestamp) - min(log.timestamp)
FROM ( 
  SELECT MAX(log_id) as log_id
  FROM log
  GROUP BY document_id) latestLog
    INNER JOIN log latestStatus ON latestStatus.log_id = latestLog.log_id
    INNER JOIN log on latestStatus.status_code = log.status_code
GROUP BY log.document_id, log.status_code
HAVING (max(log.timestamp) - min(log.timestamp)) > 600
```